# Calendar command line sample code works, but where's my calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I followed the instructions to use the Java command line sample code (CalendarSample.java).

I'm authenticating using a Service Account and a locally stored key file. I'm trying to avoid using OAuth 2 and just authenticate programatically.

```
    GoogleCredential.Builder builder = new GoogleCredential.Builder();
    builder.setTransport(httpTransport);
    builder.setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
    builder.setServiceAccountId(ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
    builder.setServiceAccountScopes(scopes);
    builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"));
    credential = builder.build();
```

where ACCOUNT_EMAIL is the long string I copied from the google console, something like

331155436243-he8e67ujkss8fgdj4di1lb7vjl4h7p6k@developer.gserviceaccount.com

I run the code, and I see the output such as:

Summary: Calendar for Testing 2

But when I go to the calendar for my own google account, I don't see the new calendars. I commented out the sample code where it deletes calendars, and when I run it again to display the existing calendars, it still shows

Summary: Calendar for Testing 2

Now, is that because it's creating the calendar in some new account (maybe accessed through that ACCOUNT_EMAIL above) rather than in my gmail account?

If I try to do

```
builder.setServiceAccountId("my.own.account@gmail.com")
```

or

```
builder.setServiceAccountUser("my.own.account@gmail.com")
```

the  authorization fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With `builder.setServiceAccountUser("my.own.account@gmail.com")` method everything should be OK. Can you show the full authorization error and source code, how you create `Calendar` object?

Comment: Thanks Michal, Here's the error: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested scopes not allowed: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
}

Comment: and I create the calendar like this, using the credential I created in the code I posted above:

client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Comment: Next time just edit the question and add additional information. It looks like you have to add permission for your service account. See this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account. Read "Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account" paragraph. It describes how to add scopes for provided service account.

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up using the standard oath2 method, which worked for me.